# How to change default to Base SAS

Tags: sas

I have base sas and sas eg installed. When I open a .sas file it opens in eg. I don't want to use the extra step of selecting 'open with'. I need the .sas to default open in base sas.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a SAS specific question. This is an OS level question. Please tag your OS for better support.

Answer (score 2):

Windows: 
Control panel > Programs> Default Programs > Set Associations > change default program associated with the extension.

Comment: I tried that but there is no default setting and no options

Comment: You tried to "associate a file type or protocol with a program"? Because I have the ability to highlight the .sas extension "name" then click "Change program..." button at top of the page.